# Можно ли в запросе SQL указать одновременно?

Tags: sql, mysql

Можно ли в запросе SQL указать одновременно `tab.*` и через запятую отдельные поля `tab.detail as D`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Откройте консоль mysql и проверьте, результат сообщите и запомните. У вас очень странные вопросы, развивайте исследовательский интерес, а не сухие факты! Пробуйте, эксперементируйте, практикуйте!

Comment: Проверил - действительно работает, а смысл был в том, чтобы для тех полей, названия которых совпадают с другими, поставить алиас.

Answer (score 1):

Можно но зачем? если у вас итак уже все поля есть .. лучше все нужные поля в селекте перечислить